# SQL Server 2005 Full Text Catalog files got deleted

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have SQL Server 2005 database. One day we noticed the production backup is not running, and the cause was that the full text catalog was offline. Further analysis showed that the full text catalog file is missing in the folder. We checked the error logs, but could not find any reason for this deletion.

Is there any possibility in SQL Server 2005 for catalog files getting deleted automatically?

Can anyone remove this file manually via Management Studio?

Comment: I'd start with a security review to see who has access to the server and that level of access within SQL Server. The "one day we noticed" is worrisome; you should get notifications any time backups fail to run to completion.

Comment: We did a security investigation, but we couldn't find anything unusual on the windows server logs or SQL server logs. The backup issue started on weekend after business hours, even though we got notification about backup failure, we noticed it on Monday morning only.

Comment: Have you searched he server to see if someone might have accidentally moved it? I've seen accidental drag operations break production only to find the folder was dragged into a subfolder.

Comment: But I assume once SQL Server is attached to these catalog files, we cant remove/rename it without detaching DB or make it offline. So possibility of accidental move is very less.